# Monitoring an under attack Server thorugh a remote endpoint

Tags: debian, security, logs

I have this Debian server that is constantly under attack as shown in its `/var/log/auth.log` file.

I was wondering if there is a best practices of monitoring it through sending all important log files to a remote endpoint via `rsync` or something of the same family. I am pretty sure that there are out there far more experienced *nix admins who probably reached better ideas for doing this hence I am open to all sorts of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a good idea to ship your logs somewhere secure, and there are a few different ways to do this.

The most basic is to get your syslog daemon to do it for you.  For a normal `syslog` you can add something like this to your `/etc/syslog.conf`:

```
*.debug        @your.remote.server.address
```

Then you can configure the syslog daemon (and your firewall) at the other end to accept and store logged events.

The downsides to this are (a) the logs are sent in the clear, and (b) syslog uses UDP by default, so your logs are not guaranteed to arrive (although they probably will!).  You could mitigate (a) by sending them down an encrypted tunnel to your log server.

A more comprehensive solution is [logstash](http://logstash.net/), which will ship your logs to a central server for indexing and storage.  It's quite a bit of work to set up, and is really suited to a situation where you have many servers' logs to collect, or you want to be able to do complex transformations and parsing on the way.